# Philosophers dealing with fundamental structure of everything using no prior assumptions

Tags: reference-request, ontology

I'm looking for authors dealing with the fundamental structure of everything, starting with no prior assumptions.
One such author is Hegel, which in [Science of Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_of_Logic) does the following:

> Hegel aims to discover the fundamental structure of everything from pure reflection alone [...]
>
> Hegel claims to begin his Science of Logic with zero assumptions[...]

[quotes source](https://ianwrightsite.wordpress.com/2018/11/24/hegelian-contradiction-and-the-prime-numbers-part-1/comment-page-1/?unapproved=740&moderation-hash=06d94f9d8daf8b78423380ead9d1fe01#comment-740)

Which are the most notable authors and/or works using similar approaches?

Comment: Not quite an answer, but I find the works of Tarski to be a useful counterpoint to those who strive for the fundamental structure of everything.

Comment: Does Nicholas Rescher qualify? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_everything_(philosophy)#Nicholas_Rescher)
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicholas_Rescher)

Comment: Anyone dealing with anything with no prior assumptions does not exist, especially Hegel, his grand claims notwithstanding. Fichte is another prominent author (and Hegel's precursor) who pretends to spin everything out of nothing (by inserting empirical observations and surmises in a veiled manner). As for authors who try to limit and control the influence of preconceptions, the most sustained effort was arguably made by [Husserl's phenomenology](https://www.iep.utm.edu/phenom/#SH2b), where suspension of prior beliefs (epoché) is a central methodological tenet.

Comment: It seems to me very few 'Western' or scholastic philosophers delve so deep. One difficulty for the question is that complexity does not go all the way down, so the phrase 'fundamental structure' may be an oxymoron..Perhaps you could check out George Spencer Brown and his book 'Laws of Form'. He gives a mathematical description of the emergence of form from formlessness. where formlessness is structureless.

Comment: The issue is that the vast majority of philosophers have some kind of prior influence and/or exposure. While I respect your absolutely fascinating thoughts, what you are seeking is simply not a common interest. I am not saying what you are requesting is invalid either.

Comment: We stand on the shoulders of giants. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_on_the_shoulders_of_giants)

Comment: It's possible that I'm just not good at searching for this kind of information. I like the way you think. I upvoted your question. However, I genuinely cannot find any authors who work from zero influence. Ayn Rand claims her only influence was Aristotle, and she is not (usually) considered credible in academic philosophy with good reason. I'm leaving this as a comment because I need to research more.

Comment: Thanks for posting this bounty! I’m working on an answer to another question on Wittgenstein‘s Tractatus, and I’ll try to work in an answer one way or the other on how his work can be brought to bear on this one.

Comment: James Ladyman, structural realism and his *Everything Must Go* - "commit ourselves only to the mathematical or structural content of our theories". And "Matteo Morganti differs from other epistemic structural realists by arguing for agnosticism about whether there is a domain of individuals over and above relational structure." https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/structural-realism/

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_realism

Answer (score 1):

David Deutsch, with his book The Fabric Of Reality, and more widely with his take on Universal Constructor Theory.

Douglas Hofstadter's work, especially Strange Loops. The closest I can think of to something like the dialectic, but with explanatory power.